# Retrieving Result in subselect by timestamp matching fields per row

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

with this query i aim to retrieve data from another table in a subquery where arguments compare unixtime stamp. But the result in my third columne ('valid') remains empty?

```
SELECT COUNT( valid.call_id )FROM calls AS valid WHERE SECOND((
SELECT conf.cca_setvalidtime FROM user_conf AS conf        
WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(conf.activ_date)) = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(valid.last_call ))        
    )) < SECOND( valid.call_duration )

) AS 'valid'
FROM calls
GROUP BY EXTRACT(
YEAR_MONTH FROM last_call )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Solution for anyone who can need something alike ;-)

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT( last_call, '%M' ) AS 'month', COUNT( call_id ) AS 'total', (

SELECT COUNT( valid.call_id )
FROM calls AS valid
WHERE TIME((


SELECT conf.cca_setvalidtime FROM user_conf AS conf        
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM conf.activ_date ) = EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM valid.last_call ) AND conf.for_role=1



)) < TIME( valid.call_duration )
AND EXTRACT(
YEAR_MONTH FROM valid.last_call ) = EXTRACT(
YEAR_MONTH FROM calls.last_call )
) AS 'valid'
FROM calls
GROUP BY EXTRACT(
YEAR_MONTH FROM last_call )
```

Comment: I suspect this one's a little 'niche'

Comment: what you mean by that?

Comment: Hopefully, no one's ever going to need something like *this* ;-)